# How to create a JAS-WS client?

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, jax-ws

On my quest to learn and understand Java web services I have made a very simple server, that adds two numbers, and I have created a `.war` file with it:

**Server code:**

```
@WebService(serviceName = "CalculatorWS")
@Stateless()
public class CalculatorWS {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "add")
    public int add(@WebParam(name = "i") int i, @WebParam(name = "j") int j) {
        int k = i + j;
        return k;
    }
}
```

I have created a `.war` file with that code and I deployed it using Jetty. Now the server is running at the address `http://localhost:8080/CalculatorWS/`.

The next step on this quest is to create a Client, that can connect to that server as ask for information.

I have followed [this NetBeans tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html), however, everything seems to be magic and I do not understand what to do. First because my main project is not in NetBeans, and seconds because this tutorial seems to be very "NetBeans dependent".

How do I create a Java Client to connect and interact with my server without using Netbeans?

Comment: which development tool are you using for the development of the jax-ws

Comment: Development tool? I am using netbeans ide and am launching the server's war file using jetty. Other than that i dont really know anything else. All i want is a simple java client that can discover the server after being launched, using java code.